# Windows Container does not resolve container by service name if using user-defined network

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have a simple `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803
CMD powershell "Start-Sleep -s 100000"
```

and `docker-compose` defining 2 services `a` and `b`:

```
version: "3.5"
    services:
        a:
           build: .
        b:
           build: .

 networks:
     default:
         external: true
         name: app
```

```

After `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` and connecting to one of containers I cannot resolve containers by their service names:

```
PS C:\> ping a
Ping request could not find host a. Please check the name and try again.
PS C:\> ping b
Ping request could not find host b. Please check the name and try again.
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName a
Resolve-DnsName : a : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName a
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (a:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERROR_INVALID_NAME,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName

PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName b
Resolve-DnsName : b : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName b
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (b:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERROR_INVALID_NAME,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName

PS C:\>
```

But if I remove `networks` section from `docker-compose` service name resolution works fine. If I create and use bridged network on Linux everything also works fine.

Is this behavior by design or am I doing something wrong?